# Django FilterSet field lookup dictionary format

Tags: python, django, django-tables2, django-filters

I am learning Django, and started creating a web app, and trying to use django_filters with django_tables2, to filter on the columns in the table. What I am tyrying to change is the default 'exact' lookup method, according to the django_filters instructions. This is the example they show at [FilterSet Options](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filterset.html)

```
class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {
            'username': ['exact', 'contains'],
            'last_login': ['exact', 'year__gt'],
        }
```

What happens is that if I don't include 'exact' in the list of lookups (like for the shop__shop field below), the field is not rendered on the page.

```
class ReceiptFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = expenses
        fields = {
            'purchase_date': ['exact'],
            'shop__shop': ['iexact'],
            'payment_method__payment_method': ['exact'],
        }
```

[Please, click here to see the web page rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvkj7.png)

If I leave 'exact' in front of the lookup I want to add (as in the instructions), it doesn't seem to have any effect, the filter works like it was an 'exact' lookup.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Miki.

P.S. Let me add some more code here.

models:

```
class shops(models.Model):
    shop = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    shop_type = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.shop
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Shop"

class expenses(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(items, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(shops, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(owners, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    currency = models.ForeignKey(currencies, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payment_method = models.ForeignKey(payment_methods, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=3)
    purchase_date = models.DateField()
    entry_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    exclude_from_reports = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    transferred = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.amount) + ' ' + self.item.unit + ' of ' + self.item.item
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Expense"
```

table:

```
class ReceiptsTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = expenses
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"
        fields = ('purchase_date','shop__shop','payment_method__payment_method','currency__currency_short','total')
```

view:

```
    def receipts(request):
        receipt_list=expenses.objects.values('purchase_date','shop__shop','payment_method__payment_method','currency__currency_short').annotate(total=Sum('price')).order_by('-purchase_date')
        filter = ReceiptFilter(request.GET, queryset=receipt_list)
        return render(request, 'household/receipts.html', {'filter':filter})
```

template:

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'household/style.css' %}">

{# <a href='/household/add_expense'>Add Expense</a> #}

{% block content %}
    <table>
        <caption>Receipts</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Shop</th>
                <th>Payment Method</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <thead>
            <form method='get'>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ filter.form.purchase_date }}</th>
                    <th>{{ filter.form.shop__shop }}</th>
                    <th>{{ filter.form.payment_method__payment_method }}</th>
                    <th><input type='submit' value='Filter'/></th>
                </tr>
            </form>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for obj in filter.qs %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ obj.purchase_date }}</td>
                <td>{{ obj.shop__shop }}</td>
                <td>{{ obj.payment_method__payment_method }}</td>
                <td>{{ obj.currency__currency_short }} {{ obj.total }}</td>
            </tr> 
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What type of field is `shop__shop`? Are you seeing any info in the browser console.log?

Comment: shop is a ForeignKey in a model to a CharField in another model--also "shop",
and this is the queryset used in the filter definition (sorry if I use the wrong term):

receipt_list=expenses.objects.values('purchase_date','shop__shop','payment_method__payment_method','currency__currency_short').annotate(total=Sum('price')).order_by('-purchase_date')

Comment: @Ben, I added more code to my post, I hope it answers more accurately what shop__shop is.

Comment: In your ReceiptFilter, in the fields, if you use `exact` instead of `iexact`, does the form show up? `fields = {'shop__shop': ['exact'],}`?

Comment: Yes, it does. But only, if the first is 'exact', and it seems any subsequent lookups have no effect.

Comment: Based on this documentation: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#the-filter I'd suggest trying to declare the "shop__shop" field in the ReceiptFilter class as `shop__shop = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')`

Comment: Thank you Ben, now the forms appears with this way of defining the lookup expression, however, the "i" pard doesn't seem to work, it's still an exact match. I tried with icontains, and istartswith too, the same happens. The lookup remains case sensitive.

Comment: Have you tried using `icontains` as the `lookup_expr`? `shop__shop = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')` https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/tips.html#missing-lookup-expr-for-text-search-filters

Comment: Yes, that's actually exactly how I have it now, but the lookup is still case sensitive.